# How Can I keep a Task from changing assignee when its parent opportunity changes owner?

Tags: process-builder, opportunity, tasks, assignment-rules, record-owner

Our BDRs have a workflow where they create a task on an opportunity and search from a spreadsheet an AE with whom to set up a meeting with the customer.

We want to remove the need for a spreadsheet and move to automatic distribution (using Distribution Engine) where the user would trigger a handoff to a new Opportunity owner.

Unfortunately, this also changes the task's owner and locks out the BDR from being able to complete that task, and I'm looking for a way to keep this from happening.

My best guess at this point would be to build a workflow in Process builder that would be logic'd something like this:

IF a task's owner role is AE

AND the task's subject is "Meeting"

THEN switch the owner to LastModifiedBy

Am I barking up the right tree or is there a more efficient way to ensure that the BDR can still be assigned to and complete their own task?

Comment: this is plausible but you need to verify that Task's Process Builder or triggers actually get invoked on a delta to Opportunity owner. Some SFDC actions on parents don't give you a hook on a downstream action on a child. If not; then you'll need a trigger or Lightning Flow on Opportunity to work through the children Tasks

Comment: I figured it out- if an admin (or non-owner) profile with sufficient permissions changes the opportunity owner, the child task won't change owner. It's only if the record owner gives their record to someone else, that their task is automatically reassigned.

Since we're using distribution engine, a separate automated account will be performing the actual reassignment. I'd built that functionality out in our staging environment, but hadn't yet built it out in prod at the time I built it out. Lesson learned!

@cropredy thank you for taking the time to respond!

Comment: as a favor to the community; use the Your Answer section to answer the question

Comment: Thanks for the tip - I'm new here :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I figured it out- if an admin (or non-owner) profile with sufficient permissions changes the opportunity owner, the child task won't change owner. It's only if the record owner gives their record to someone else, that their task is automatically reassigned. Since we're using distribution engine, a separate automated account will be performing the actual reassignment. I'd built that functionality out in our staging environment, but hadn't yet built it out in prod at the time I built it out. Lesson learned! @cropredy thank you for taking the time to respond!

Comment: you should be able to accept this as the answer too!

Comment: Got it, thanks again!